# Java NullPointerException when referencing object array

Tags: java

I have the following program:

```
class Books 
{
    String title;
    String author;
}

class BookTestDrive 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
        int x = 0;
        myBooks[0].title = "The Grapes of Java";
        myBooks[1].title = "The Java Gatsby";
        myBooks[2].title = "The Java Cookbook";
        myBooks[0].author = "bob";
        myBooks[1].author = "sue";
        myBooks[2].author = "ian";

        while (x < 3) 
        {
            System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
            System.out.print(" by ");
            System.out.println(myBooks[x].author);
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it gives me the following error when I execute it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BookTestDrive.main(Books.java:14)
```

I am new to Java. The code looks legitimate from my C/C++ experience...How to resolve this problem?

Comment: which of them is line 14?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that you have only created the array of books in the following lines -

```
Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
```

You still need to initialize each element in the array to a book object before accessing them.

An example code would look like -

```
Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
int x = 0;
myBooks[0] = new Books();
myBooks[0].title = "The Grapes of Java";
```

You need to do this for all elements in your array.

Answer (score 2):

I second the answer from @AnandSKumar (it is the direct answer to the problem after all), but because it is a matter of beauty, I could not leave without making following few changes:

```
public class Play {
  static public class Book {
    final public String title;
    final public String author;
    public Book(String title,String author) { 
      this.title = title; 
      this.author = author; 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "\""+title+"\" by "+author;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
      Book [] books = new Book[] {
        new Book("The Grapes of Java","bob"),
        new Book("The Java Gatsby","sue"),
        new Book("The Java Cookbook","ian"),
      };

      for (Book book:books) {
          System.out.println(book);
      }
  }
}
```

1. You can [initialize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) in-line the content of your [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
2. If you represent 'a single book' then we should name the class representing it as `Book` and not `Books` to avoid confusion.
3. We can enhance the `Book` class with an improved `toString()`, and use that instead.
4. There is a [enhanced `for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) iterator to loop over your array.
5. Note that the third position book in the array, also ends with a comma, although there is no element following it. This could have been a mistake, but it this case it was a deliberate choice. Makes it easier to copy-paste into next elements without introducing errors, as the Java syntax allows for it.
6. Because once a book is created, title and author should not change anymore, it might be good to design the `Book` class to be 'Immutable'. For this reason a constructor was added, and the `title` and `author` fields set as final. You could also consider making them private, and provide getters.